# Foundry pranking different in test contract vs contract

Tags: testing, foundry, test

I have a test in foundry where I prank `msg.sender` as such:

```
address USER = address(1);
vm.startPrank(USER);
myContract.doStuff();
console.log("msg.sender from test", msg.sender);
vm.stopPrank();
```

And in `myContract`, I have:

```
function doStuff() public {
    console.log("msg.sender from contract", msg.sender);
```

And as an output, I get:

```
msg.sender from test 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
msg.sender from contract 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Is this correct? Why is `msg.sender` not being pranked in my test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The `prank` cheatcode only applies to calls made from your tests; you cannot use the prank cheatcodes to change the `msg.sender` of the test functions themselves.

To quote the [Foundry Book](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/prank?highlight=prank#prank) (emphasis mine):

> Sets `msg.sender` to the specified address for the **next call**.

Worth noting that you can change the default `msg.sender` used for test functions by setting the [`sender`](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/tree/d1c84e3e756c00a5baeab2a7714786e4885d4b0c/config) option in your Foundry config:

```
# foundry.toml
[profile.default]
sender = "0xcafe..."
```