# vm.startPrank doesn't change the msg.sender in foundry

Tags: uniswap, testing, foundry, forge

While I'm performing the testing in foundry. I'm facing an issue of vm.startPrank doesn't change the msg.sender.

```
CheatCodes cheats = CheatCodes(0x7109709ECfa91a80626fF3989D68f67F5b1DD12D);
address userAcct = address(0xA6466D12A42B4496CD8ce61343aF392A8d7Bd871);
IERC20 UMT = IERC20(0xca861e289f04cB9C67fd6b87ca7EAFa59192f164); 

//setting up BSC mainnet fork
function setUp() public { 
        cheats.createSelectFork("bsc");
    }

//Performing the swap and startprank

 function testSwap() public {
        vm.startPrank(userAcct,userAcct);
        console.log("Message.Sender", msg.sender);
        console.log("This address", address(this));
        console.log("TX origin",tx.origin);

        uint256 userBalance = UMT.balanceOf(userAcct);
        console.log(userBalance);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }
```

As mentioned into the Foundry docs vm.startPrank will change the **msg.sender** but when I'm console logging it I'm still getting the **default address**.

**Output**

```
Message.Sender 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
  This address 0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496  
  TX origin 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38     
  4590405000000000000000

Traces:
  [19408] SwapTest::testSwap()
    ├─ [0] console::log(Fork Completed) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0xA6466D12A42B4496CD8ce61343aF392A8d7Bd871, 0xA6466D12A42B4496CD8ce61343aF392A8d7Bd871)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] console::log(Message.Sender, DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] console::log(This address, SwapTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] console::log(TX origin, DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [2909] 0xca861e289f04cB9C67fd6b87ca7EAFa59192f164::balanceOf(0xA6466D12A42B4496CD8ce61343aF392A8d7Bd871) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f8d8aaa27df1008000
    ├─ [0] console::f5b1bba9(0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f8d8aaa27df1008000) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::stopPrank()
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← ()
```

Comment: I think the answer to your question is explained here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/147323/116116

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foundry pranking different in test contract vs contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147319/foundry-pranking-different-in-test-contract-vs-contract)

Comment: No. In that question OP was using only vm.prank and the answer suggests to use the vm.startPrank, whereas I'm using vm.startPrank already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it this way would be a more accurate test:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract address_test {
    function retSender() external view returns(address, address) {
        return (msg.sender, tx.origin);
    }
}
```

```
CheatCodes cheats = CheatCodes(0x7109709ECfa91a80626fF3989D68f67F5b1DD12D);
address userAcct = address(0xA6466D12A42B4496CD8ce61343aF392A8d7Bd871);
IERC20 UMT = IERC20(0xca861e289f04cB9C67fd6b87ca7EAFa59192f164); 

//setting up BSC mainnet fork
function setUp() public { 
        cheats.createSelectFork("bsc");
    }

//Performing the swap and startprank

 function testSwap() public {
        vm.startPrank(userAcct, tx.origin);
        console.log("Message.Sender", msg.sender);
        console.log("This address", address(this));
        console.log("TX origin",tx.origin);
        address addr;
        address origin;
        (addr, origin) = membership.retSender();
        console.log("In contract Message.Sender", addr);
        console.log("In contract TX origin", origin);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }
```

In this case, I received the expected sender's address upon fulfillment of the contract

```
[PASS] testSwap() (gas: 17789)
Logs:
  Message.Sender 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
  This address 0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496
  TX origin 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
  In contract Message.Sender 0xA6466D12A42B4496CD8ce61343aF392A8d7Bd871 <== 
  In contract TX origin 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38 <==
```